# Sufficient conditions for quasi-isometric embeddings of Cayley graph

Tags: geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I would like to know more about the assumptions under which the Cayley graph of a given group embeds quasi-isometrically into the space where the group is acting.
For instance, if a group $G$ acts by isometries and properly discontinuously on a proper metric space $X$, with compact quotient $X/G$, then its Cayley graph quasi-isometrically embeds into $X$. I'm interested in this kind of results. Any comment would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you only want a quasi-isometric embedding and not a quasi-isometry, you can drop the requirement that the quotient is compact.

Comment: Google "undistorted subgroup" and you will get many references with such examples.

Comment: @Martian: if you drop the cocompactness, the embedding can be or not be quasi-isometric.

Comment: @Yves Really?  I was under the opposite impression.  Is there a canonical counterexample you can point me to?

Comment: @Martian: the group $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the upper half plane (with the hyperbolic plane distance) by $n\cdot z=z+n$. So $d(z,nz)\sim \log(n)$. Thus the map $z\mapsto n\cdot z$ is not a quasi-isometric embedding.